# YN600EX-RT Flash functions

Tags: yongnuo

Where can I locate the basic operation instructions for the Yongnuo Speedlite YN600EX-RT Flash?

Comment: google this?   Yongnuo Speedlite YN600EX-RT Flash filetype:pdf

Comment: voting to close as this appears easily searchable on the web

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted the text from your question into Google. The 5th [result](http://www.hkyongnuo.com/e-detaily.php?ID=351) returned this manual inside of it: http://yongnuo.com.cn/usermanual/pdf/YN600EX-RTy.pdf

You also can just search for "Yongnuo Speedlite YN600EX-RT manual" and return the same link as the first result.